# Parsing complex and changing JSON data in Python, several levels deep

Tags: python, json, list, parsing, dictionary

I am trying to parse changing JSON data, however the JSON data is a bit complex and changes wtih each iteration.

The JSON data is being parsed inside a loop so each time the loop runs, the json data is different.  I'm focused right now on the education data.

**THE JSON DATA:**

First one might look like this:

```
{u'gender': u'female', u'id': u'15394'}
```

Next one might be:

```
{
u'gender': u'male', u'birthday': u'12/10/1983', u'location': {u'id': '12', u'name': u'Mexico City, Mexico'}, u'hometown': {u'id': u'19', u'name': u'Mexico City, Mexico'}, 

u'education': [
{
u'school': {u'id': u'22', u'name': u'Institut Saint Dominique de Rome'}, 
u'type': u'High School', 
u'year': {u'id': u'33', u'name': u'2002'}
}, 
{
u'school': {u'id': u'44', u'name': u'Instituto Cumbres'}, 
u'type': u'High School', 
u'year': {u'id': u'55', u'name': u'1999'}
}, 
{
u'school': {u'id': u'66', u'name': u'Chantemerle International School'},    
u'type': u'High School', 
u'year': {u'id': u'77', u'name': u'1998'}
}, 
{
u'school': {u'id': u'88', u'name': u'Columbia University'}, 
u'type': u'College', 
u'concentration': 
[{u'id': u'91', u'name': u'Economics'}, 
{u'id': u'92', u'name': u'Film Studies'}]
}
], 
u'id': u'100384'}
```

I am trying to return all the values for school name, school id and school type, so essentially I want `[education][school][id]`, `[education][school][name]`, `[education][school][type]` in one line.  However, every person has a different number of schools listed and different types of schools or no schools at all.  I want to return each school with its associated name, id and type on a new line within my existing loop.

**IDEAL OUTPUT**:

```
1   34  Boston Latin School High School
1   26  Harvard University  College
1   22  University of Michigan  Graduate School
```

The one in this case refers to a friend_id, which I have already set up to append to the list as the first item in each loop.

**I've tried:**

```
friend_data = response.read()
friend_json = json.loads(friend_data)

#This below is inside a loop pulling data for each friend:

try:
    for school_id in friend_json['education']:
        school_id = school_id['school']['id']
        friendedu.append(school_id)
    for school_name in friend_json['education']:
        school_name = school_name['school']['name']
        friendedu.append(school_name)
    for school_type in friend_json['education']:
        school_type = school_type['type']
        friendedu.append(school_type)
except:
    school_id = "NULL"
```

print friendedu
writer.writerow(friendedu)

**CURRENT OUTPUT:**

`[u'22', u'44', u'66', u'88', u'Institut Saint Dominique de Rome', u'Instituto Cumbres', u'Chantemerle International School', u'Columbia University', u'High School', u'High School', u'High School', u'College']`

This output is just a list of the values it has pulled, instead I'm trying to organize the output as shown above.  I think that perhaps another for-loop is called for since for one person I want each school to be on its own line.  Right now, the `friendedu` list is appending all the education info for one person into each line of the list.  I want each education item in a new line and then move on to the next person and continue to write rows for the next person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about

```
friend_data = response.read()
friend_json = json.loads(friend_data)


if 'education' in friend_json.keys():
    for school_id in friend_json['education']:
        friendedu = []
        try:
            friendedu.append(school_id['school']['id'])
            friendedu.append(school_name['school']['name'])
            friendedu.append(school_type['school']['type'])
        except:
            friendedu.append('School ID, NAME, or type not found')
        print(" ".join(friendedu))
```

Comment: The edit above seems to have solved the problem, thanks

Comment: @kegewe Great, if the answer worked for you, would you mind accepting it as a solution?

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv
import json
import requests

def student_schools(student, fields=["id", "name", "type"], default=None):
    schools = student.get("education", [])
    return ((school.get(field, default) for field in fields) for school in schools)

def main():
    res = requests.get(STUDENT_URL).contents
    students = json.loads(res)

    with open(OUTPUT, "wb") as outf:
        outcsv = csv.writer(outf)
        for student in students["results"]:    # or whatever the root label is
            outcsv.writerows(student_schools(student))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: the problem is that my initial try and except section is part of a much larger for loop.  I need to add another variable from another part of the loop into the beginning of each `friendedu` line.  I've already pulled the JSON data into friend_json, so I don't have to do any additional url requests.  I simply want to put the data from each student into 1 or more lines in the `friendedu` list.  I then want to add those 1 or more lines to a csv file below the previous student.

Answer (score 1):

You certainly don't need more for loops.

One will do:

```
friendedu = []
for school_id in friend_json['education']:
    friendedu.append("{id} {name} {type}".format(
        id=school_id['school']['id'],
        name=school_name['school']['name'],
        type=school_type['school']['type'])
```

Or a list comprehension:

```
friendedu = ["{id} {name} {type}".format(
    id=school_id['school']['id'],
    name=school_name['school']['name'],
    type=school_type['school']['type']) for school_id in friend_json['education']]
```

Comment: I'm getting `keyword error: non-keyword arg after keyword arg`

Comment: I'd left off `type=` on the final line. Updated.